# does not detect wifi usb inmua

Tags: wireless

I have a USB Wifi called Inmua. When I execute the command "lsusb",I get the following information:

Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter

I can't find a way that when I run "ip a" that device appears

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180

Comment: You have the exact same device as the duplicate. You need the same fix.